# Ant design validator in Nextjs

Tags: validation, next.js, antd

guys~ I start trying to finish my form design in these few days, but I've faced some problems now, hope can learn some advice here, I was looking for many answers before asking, but still not what I'm looking for.

Here is my problem~~

```
const [minLength, setMinLength] = useState('');
const [maxLength, setMaxLength] = useState('');
...
...

      <Form.Item label='Length'>
          <Form.Item
            name='length'
            noStyle
            rules={[
              {
                validator: async (_, minLength, maxLength) => {
                  if (maxLength < minLength && maxLength !== (null || '')) {
                    return Promise.reject(
                      new Error('Min can not bigger than max!')
                    );
                  } else if (
                    minLength === (null || '') &&
                    maxLength !== (null || '')
                  ) {
                    return Promise.reject(new Error('Please fill min first!'));
                  }
                },
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input.Group compact>
              <InputNumber
                name='minLength'
                style={{ width: 100, textAlign: 'center', borderRight: 0 }}
                placeholder='Minimum'
                value={minLength}
                onChange={setMinLength}
              />
              <Input
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  borderLeft: 0,
                  borderRight: 0,
                  pointerEvents: 'none',
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                }}
                placeholder='~'
                disabled
              />
              <InputNumber
                name='maxLength'
                style={{
                  width: 100,
                  borderLeft: 0,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                }}
                placeholder='Maximum'
                value={maxLength}
                onChange={setMaxLength}
              />
              <span
                style={{
                  position: 'relative',
                  margin: '0 8px',
                  top: '3px',
                  fontSize: '18px',
                }}
              >
                吋
              </span>
              <Button
                icon={<RedoOutlined />}
                onClick={() => {
                  setMinLength('');
                  setMaxLength('');
                }}
              >
                Reset
              </Button>
            </Input.Group>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form.Item>
```

The validator doesn't work in here, did I set something wrong??
I want to learn how to custom my own validator in my other Input or Select, I know use rules in Form.Item for 'require' or 'pattern' is common, but I hope can learn something special and new here~~

Any advice will be helpful~~ It will means a lot for me!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [API reference](https://ant.design/components/form/#Rule) for `validator` functions. They take two arguments: the rule itself and the current value of the form field. As is, you're passing in three arguments, which makes no sense.

Besides that, you should wrap each `Input` component in its own `Form.Item` (instead of having a single parent one). You can look at the [Complex Form Control example](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-complex-form-control) from the documentation to see how it's done.

Comment: OK~~, before you reply, I'm trying to add a Form.Item between Input later XD, and I'll try to figure it out if it's work, then ask you later!!! Thanks ~ give some time to try this solution!!